# Flutter constructor error

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem with a code snippet I tried to play with, and since I am new to **dart** I don't really understand the error message. Can somebody explain to me why the error message says

> The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type
>   'widget'.

and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `MaterialList` doesn't exist. It looks like maybe you meant [`TwoLevelList`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TwoLevelList-class.html), which is deprecated. You should try [`ListView`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have other import statements try to use alias as some libraries may be the reason for conflict.

Example: import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;