# Flutter - named parameters aren't defined

Tags: dart, flutter

Trying to create a list following code used [here](https://hackernoon.com/flutter-iii-lists-and-items-6bfa7348ab1b) but can't get around the syntax error

```
class _ContactListItem extends ListView {

  _ContactListItem(Contact contact) :
    super(
      title : new Text(contact.fullName),
      subtitle: new Text(contact.email),
      leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(contact.fullName[0]))
  );

}
```

The error is "The named parameter 'title' isn't defined." There same error exists for subtitle and leading as well (I assume fixing one may address all though). Totally new to flutter and dart so any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio Solution: Files > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 2):

Your `_ContactListItem` extends from the wrong widget.
You extended from `ListView` but you're supposed to extend from `ListItem`

Answer (score 0):

The article seems outdated. You should look at the sample codes available on [ListView docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to extend ListTile instead of ListView. I also had to change the ContactList class in order to get it to run. What I have now is

```
class _ContactListItem extends ListTile {

  _ContactListItem(Contact contact) :
    super(
      title : new Text(contact.fullName),
      subtitle: new Text(contact.email),
      leading: new CircleAvatar(child: new Text(contact.fullName[0]))
  );

}
```

The ContactList class is changed as per the constructor error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550997/flutter-constructor-error) post

```
class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {

final List<Contact> _contacts;

ContactList(this._contacts);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new ListView(
  //type: MaterialListType.twoLine,
    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
    children: _buildContactList()
);
}

List<_ContactListItem> _buildContactList() {
return _contacts.map((contact) => new _ContactListItem(contact))
    .toList();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the extracted flutter sdk folder and extracting it and recreating the new project helped resolve all the errors.Hope it works for you as well